# How to get Current HTML element height and width property in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to access height and width property of current html `img` element to apply `ngClass` dynamically based on property.

I have this code for html

```
<div class="cfg-pg-outer-box" ng-repeat="album in album_list">
    <div class="cfg-pg-photo-box">
        <img ng-src="{{album.thumbnail.image_path}}" ng-class="myclass(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using AngularJS to apply `ngClass` dynamically

```
$scope.myclass = function(element) {    
    return (element.width > element.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
}
```

I am not able to read width and height properties. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Does `album.thumbnail` object have this information maybe like height/width? Do you really need to read it from image object?

Comment: Try `element.offsetWidth`/`element.offsetHeight`

Comment: @dfsq No album.thumnail do not have this information.

Comment: @Dr.Molle element.offsetWidth/element.offsetHeight giving undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that unlike regular HTML event attributes like `onclick`, `ngClass` and similar have different  context of invocation. To be exact `this` points to current scope object.

In your case you should write a custom directive to read/operate with DOM element. For example simple directive can look like:

```
app.directive('dimentionClass', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var img = element[0];
            img.onload = function() {
                img.className = img.width > img.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and you will use it like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{album.thumbnail.image_path}}" dimention-class />
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GtklqTUvtbFxb6AFuz4S?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use element.offsetWidth and element.offsetHeight

Comment: Giving undefined inside $scope.myclass function.

Comment: try element[0].offsetWidth

Answer (score 1):

```
var width = document.getElementById('<Element's ID>').offsetWidth;
var height= document.getElementById('<Element's ID>').offseHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $scope.$apply, otherwise any changes to $scope made in non-Angular event handlers won't be processed properly:

$scope.myclass = function(element) {

```
$scope.image.width = img.width;
$scope.image.height = img.height;
$scope.image.path = $scope.imageurl;
$scope.$apply();

   return (this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = document.body.clientHeight;
var width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

[Explanation](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, try using:

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementId");

var height = element.style.height;
var width =  element.style.width;
```

**EDIT2:**

You might also wanna try:

```
document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).offsetHeight;
```

and/or

```
document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).clientHeight;
```

Comment: I believe it gives height/width of whole window , but I needs  height/width of that element only.